# é becomes Ã© and à becomes Ã in meta description when i share the website url from iphone to whatsapp

Tags: ios, iphone, drupal, whatsapp

In the meta description, when i share the website's URL from iPhone to Whatsapp, the french accents are encoded to ANSI.
EX : é becomes Ã© and à becomes Ã

Attached is the screenshot of the problem

Thanks in advance

[Sharing URL from iPhone to whatsapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGX8y.png)

Comment: So have you been able to find any more information out since you posted this on the drupal.org issue tracker for [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/3221744)?

Comment: @treckstar not yet